# vba sendkeys application invisible

Tags: vba

Can you use sendkeys with application visible = false?

```
Application.Visible = false
Application.SendKeys ("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

It is like hitting the keyboard. The keys will go to the window that has focus. If the window is invisible it cannot have the focus, therefore cannot receive the keys.

Comment: Is there any option to enter characters in internet explorer invisibly?

Comment: @sebastian Now it obviously happened that you run into a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In your original question you asked `X` but your actual problem was `Y`. That barely never leads to a good solution. So please open up a new question, add the code you have tried. Explain your **actual** problem and how you think to solve it and tell where you got stuck or errors. Meanwhile I recommend you to google for a tutorial of "webscraping with VBA" there are a lot.